# Do blowups generate the birational equivalence relation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, blow-ups

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are birational varieties (projective, irreducible, over $\mathbb C$) of the same dimention. Is there a sequence of blow-ups and blow-downs that makes $Y$ from $X$?

Comment: I think this is a version of the "weak factorization theorem".

Comment: ... provided $X$ and $Y$ are smooth.

Comment: Let $X-\to Y$ be a rational map. There is a projective birational $X'\to X$ such that $X'\to Y$ is everywhere defined (take for $X'$ the closure of a "graph" of $X-\to Y$). Now, by Hartshorne Theorem II 7.17, both maps $X'\to X$ and $X'\to Y$ are blowups. So there is a sequence of length two. Of course the question is more complicated when you want the varieties and blowup centers to be smooth (see Will Sawin's comment).